# How to find all the id's from data-id attribute array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a table list where I've some name and value row. Whenever I click one of them, I can get the id of that clicked element but I also need other id's of that table. It's an option selected table, if I select some keyword from the dropdown it will return the list of the name and value of that associated option. However, I have found all the name and value of that list but I can't seem to find the id's of them, I can only extract the clicked item id. This is how I find them :

HTML code :

```
<tbody class="dataTable" id="dataTable">`
   for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
       html += `<tr id="packageTypeRow${i}">
     <td class="tname">${response[i].name}</td>
     <td class="tvalue">${response[i].value}</td>
     <button class="edit-button" data-id="${response[i].id}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
}
```

`data-id="${response[i].id}` this has all the id's.

I've only given the code parts which I think are necessary. 
and the form

```
<form:input path="id" id="list_id" type="hidden" class="list_id"/>
<form:input path="type" id="type" type="hidden" class="list_type"/>
<!-- below will have input for name and value !-->
```

And my jquery is this :

```
var name = getting the input value;
var value =  input value;
var id = $(this).data('id') /// it return's the exact id which I've clicked

var allValue =  $(document).find('table td.tvalue').map(function() {
            return this.innerText;
        }).get(); // this return all the value from the table
var allName =  $(document).find('table td.tname').map(function() {
            return this.innerText;
        }).get();
```

But all I want is this `allvalue` and `allname` should not return the value of the clicked id.
Suppose my table has this values:

```
**name value id**
Apple AP    123
Orange OR   500
Banana BA   127
```

now, if I click orange , then this `allValue` or `allName` should return only [Apple,Banana] and [AP, BA] . But instead of this, it returns all including [Orange,OR]. But I don't want that as it breaks some conditions. That's why I want to modify `$(document).find('table td.tname')` code adding the orange id, so that it only return other two elements by using the id of orange and I also I can't filter the `orange value` as what if the table has duplicate name or value.

I tried to do this in these ways:
`$(document).find('table td.tname :not(id)')` but I guess this is not the right way. Or I want the id's of apple: `data-id: 123`, banana `data-id:127`,  whenever I click orange element button. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: For future reference it's much clearer if you show all relevant code instead of multiple paragraphs describing snippets of it

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, i doubt those part will make the whole process much complicated that's why I didn't upload them, only added the part which should be the main focus and I think they're relevant

Comment: I meant more terms of creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the issue and goal.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can select the `.tvalue` and `.tname` elements relevant to the clicked `.edit-button` and use `not()` to exclude them from the jQuery object you use to `map()` the arrays:

```js
$('.edit-button').on('click', function() {
  let $btn = $(this);
  let $row = $btn.closest('tr');
  let $name = $row.find('.tname');
  let $value = $row.find('.tvalue');
  let id = $btn.data('id');

  let allValues = $(document).find('table td.tvalue').not($value).map((i, el) => el.innerText).get();
  let allNames = $(document).find('table td.tname').not($name).map((i, el) => el.innerText).get();

  console.log(allValues);
  console.log(allNames);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="dataTable" id="dataTable">
    <tr>
      <td class="tname">Apple</td>
      <td class="tvalue">AP</td>
      <td><button class="edit-button" data-id="123"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tname">Orange</td>
      <td class="tvalue">OR</td>
      <td><button class="edit-button" data-id="500"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tname">BAnana</td>
      <td class="tvalue">BA</td>
      <td><button class="edit-button" data-id="127"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if the table is not dynamic you could build the arrays once on page load and filter the result on each button click:

```js
let allValues = $(document).find('table td.tvalue').map((i, el) => el.innerText).get();
let allNames = $(document).find('table td.tname').map((i, el) => el.innerText).get();

$('.edit-button').on('click', function() {
  let $btn = $(this);
  let $row = $btn.closest('tr');
  let name = $row.find('.tname').text();
  let value = $row.find('.tvalue').text();
  let id = $btn.data('id');

  let filteredValues = allValues.filter(v => v !== value);
  let filteredNames = allNames.filter(v => v !== name);
  
  console.log(filteredValues);
  console.log(filteredNames);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="dataTable" id="dataTable">
    <tr>
      <td class="tname">Apple</td>
      <td class="tvalue">AP</td>
      <td><button class="edit-button" data-id="123"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tname">Orange</td>
      <td class="tvalue">OR</td>
      <td><button class="edit-button" data-id="500"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tname">BAnana</td>
      <td class="tvalue">BA</td>
      <td><button class="edit-button" data-id="127"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would also suggest using `$('#dataTable')` instead of `$(document)` to make the `td` selectors more performant and accurate.

Comment: actually, I've already filtered in this way. but I want the id's mainly as for some reason what if there are duplicate values. I want to have the data-id of apple, and banana 123, 127.

Comment: my bad, I've explained it in a different way.